# Wordpress 404 override

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I've got a Wordpress site running here which displays custom content if a page/blog post isn't found. It works perfectly on the front end - but when the site loads, it sends a 404 status for all of the custom content pages.

As a consequence, none of the custom content pages are crawled by Google, which isn't ideal.

I looked at disabling the 404 redirect function in wp-app.php (lines 1277-1286) but this didn't solve the problem. I'm wondering if the status_header function (line 1652 onwards in wp-includes/functions.php) would be a better place to go, but I've had no luck with it either.

Anyone come across this, and could anyone offer any ideas?

Comment: I used to use this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/404-on-custom-non-wordpress-pages but its stopped working.